# How could I (painlessly) split or reverse "Last, First" within a record in Miller?

Tags: text-processing, csv, json, miller

I have a tab-delimited file where one of the columns is in the format "LastName, FirstName". What I want to do is split that record out into two separate columns, `last`, and `first`, use `cut` or some other verb(s) on *that*, and output the result to JSON.

I should add that I'm not married to JSON, and I know how to use other tools like [`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq), but it would be nice to get it in that format in one step.

The syntax for the `nest` verb looks like it requires memorizing a lot of frankly non-memorable options, so I figured that there would be a simple DSL operation to do this job. Maybe that's not the case?

Here's what I've tried. (Let's just forget about the extra space that's attached to `Firstname` right now, OK? I would use `strip` or `ssub` or something to get rid of that later.)

```
echo -e "last_first\nLastName, Firstname" \
  | mlr --t2j put '$o=splitnv($last_first,",")'

# result:
# { "last_first": "LastName, Firstname", "o": "(error)" }

# expected something like:
# { "last_first": "LastName, Firstname", "o": { 1: "LastName", 2: "Firstname" } }
#
# or:
# { "last_first": "LastName, Firstname", "o": [ "LastName", "Firstname" ] }
```

Why `(error)`? Is it not reasonable that assigning to `$o` as above would assign a new column `o` to the result of `splitnv`?

Here's something else I tried that didn't work like I would've expected either:

```
echo -e "last_first\nLastName, Firstname" \
  | mlr -T nest --explode --values --across-fields --nested-fs , -f last_first

# result (no delimiter here, just one field, confirmed w/ 'cat -A')
# last_first
# LastName, Firstname

# expected:
# last_first_1<tab>last_first_2
# LastName,<tab> Firstname
```

**Edit**: The problem with the command above is I should've used `--tsv`, **not** `-T`, which is a synonym for `--nidx --fs tab` (numerically-indexed columns). Problem is, Miller doesn't produce an error message when it's obviously wrong to ask for named columns in that case, which might be a mis-feature; see [issue #233](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/issues/233).

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add a sample input and a sample output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if I understand your request.

If I run

```
echo -e "last_first\nLastName, Firstname" | \
mlr --t2j --jlistwrap --jvstack nest --explode --values --across-fields --nested-fs "," -f last_first \
then clean-whitespace
```

I have

```
[
{
  "last_first_1": "LastName",
  "last_first_2": "Firstname"
}
]
```

And if I run

```
echo -e "last_first\nLastName, Firstname" | \
mlr --tsv nest --explode --values --across-fields --nested-fs "," -f last_first \
then clean-whitespace
```

I have

```
last_first_1    last_first_2
LastName        Firstname
```

Comment: Grazie Signore! I didn't even realize there was a `clean-whitespace` verb. My question was written quickly before I forgot everything, and needs some serious editing. I'll fix up the _question_, then mark this as the accepted solution, because I think the whole entirety of my problem was using `-T` (only good for files with no header line) instead of  `--tsv`, which does what I'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to switch `LastName, FirstName` to be `FirstName LastName` using DSL expressions:

```bsh
echo -e "last_first\nLastName, Firstname\nAnotherLast, AnotherFirst" \
  | mlr --t2j \
    put -q 'o=splitnv($last_first,",");
            first_last=strip(o[2]) . " " . o[1];
            emit first_last'

# result:
# { "first_last": "Firstname LastName" }
# { "first_last": "AnotherFirst AnotherLast" }
```

I think the fact that the `emit` seems to be required(?) was the key part that I didn't understand before.

It is, sadly, *not* much easier than using the `nest` verb and all its required flags.

Comment: An alternative is to use reorder `echo -e "last_first\nLastName, Firstname" | 
mlr --t2j --jlistwrap --jvstack nest --explode --values --across-fields --nested-fs "," -f last_first then clean-whitespace then reorder -f last_first_2,last_first_1`